# Php fputcsv trouble to Col

Tags: php, csv

I get name and data from html. I want write it in to CSV.

So I get this CSV.

```
 ColA    ColB         ColC   ColD   ColE   ColF   ColG
 name1   surname1     data1  data2   data3 data4 data5
 name2   surname2     data6  data7   data8 data9 data10
 name3   surname3     data11 data12  data13 data14 data15
 name..n surname..n data..n data..n  data..n data..n data..n
```

But I want name and surname in ColA.

```
     ColA           ColB   ColC   ColD   ColE   ColF  
 name1 surname1     data1  data2   data3 data4 data5
 name2 surname2     data6  data7   data8 data9 data10
 name3 surname3     data11 data12  data13 data14 data15
 name..n surname..n data..n data..n  data..n data..n data..n
```

I think because "space" 's  name and surname (some have mid name) but Data not have a space. I want write name and surname in ColA. Plzzz help me. T-T

```
 $fp = fopen("data.csv","w");
   $string = '';
    for ($i=0; $i<$count_name; $i++)
{
while ( $iterate <= 5 and $j < $count_data )
{
    $string = $string.$temp_data[$j]." ";
    $j++;
    $iterate++;
}
$csv_string = $temp_name[$i]." ".$string;
//echo $temp_name[$i];
$array = explode(' ',$csv_string);
//var_dump($array);
fputcsv($fp,$array);
//$string = "";
$iterate = 1;
$string = "";

}
```

Comment: Please, try to be more clear about what you want. You want to read and CSV and put into an html, that's it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you should try this:

```
$fp = fopen('data.csv', 'w');
for(/* Each line of data you have */){
    $colA = $name ." ".$surname; // Concatenate name and surname that you have received from your html
    $colB = $data1; // Data1 from html
    $colC = $data2; // Data2 from html
    fputcsv($fp, array($colA,$colB,$colC)); // A new line on your csv
}
fclose($fp);
```